# Восстановление ранее обученных слоев в Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Я обучил сеть и хочу переиспользовать ее слои в другой сети. Когда нет нормализации это делается просто

```
hidden_1 = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("DNN/hidden_1/Elu:0")
```

для

```
hidden_1 = tf.layers.dense(X, n_layers_1, activation=tf.nn.elu, name="hidden_1")
```

Но когда я добавляю нормализацию, активацию приходится добавлять отдельно.

```
      hidden_2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden_1, n_layers_2, name="hidden_2")
      hidden_2_norn = batch_norm_layer(hidden_2, name="hidden_2_norn")
      hidden_2_act = tf.nn.relu(hidden_3, name="hidden_2_act")

batch_norm_layer = partial(tf.layers.batch_normalization, training=training, momentum=0.9)
```

В таком раскладе я не очень понимаю что именно указывать в качестве имени, это будет как три слоя или один.

Результаты get_operations

```
DNN/hidden_1/MatMul
DNN/hidden_1/BiasAdd 
DNN/hidden_1/Elu
DNN/hidden_2/MatMul
DNN/hidden_2/BiasAdd
DNN/hidden_3/moments/mean/reduction_indices
DNN/hidden_3/moments/mean
DNN/hidden_3/moments/StopGradient
DNN/hidden_3/moments/SquaredDifference
DNN/hidden_3/moments/variance/reduction_indices
DNN/hidden_3/moments/variance
DNN/hidden_3/moments/Squeeze
DNN/hidden_3/moments/Squeeze_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond/switch_t
DNN/hidden_3/cond/switch_f
DNN/hidden_3/cond/pred_id
DNN/hidden_3/cond/Switch_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond/Switch_2
DNN/hidden_3/cond/Merge
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/switch_t
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/switch_f
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/pred_id
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/Switch_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/Switch_2
DNN/hidden_3/cond_1/Merge
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/switch_t
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/switch_f
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/pred_id
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/decay
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/mul
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/AssignMovingAvg/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/Switch_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond_2/Merge
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/switch_t
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/switch_f
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/pred_id
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg/decay
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg/sub
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg/sub/Switch_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg/mul
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/AssignMovingAvg/Switch
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/Switch_1
DNN/hidden_3/cond_3/Merge
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/add/y
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/add
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/Rsqrt
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/mul
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/mul_1
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/mul_2
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/sub
DNN/hidden_3/batchnorm/add_1
DNN/hidden_4 ##
```